# $LU$ Factorization of a nonsingular matrix with a particular pattern

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, complexity, matrix-factorization

> Consider $S\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ whose nonzero elements have the following pattern for $n = 8$: 
>   $$\begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \mu_1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
> 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \mu_2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
> 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \mu_3 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & \alpha & \beta & 0 & 0 & 0\\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & \gamma & \delta & 0 & 0 & 0\\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & \delta_1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & \delta_2 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & \delta_3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
> \end{pmatrix}$$
>   The pattern generalizes to any $n$ easily. Assume that for any $n$, $S$ is a nonsingular matrix.
>
> a.) We have considered several basic transformations (Gauss transforms, Gauss Jordan transforms, elementary permutations, Household reflectors) that can be used to compute the factorizations efficiently.
>
> Using what ever combination of these transformations, describe an algorithm to compute stably a factorization of $S$ for any $n$ that can be used to solve $Sx = b$. Your algorithm should be designed to require as few computations as possible. Your solution must include a description of how you exploit the structure of the matrix and its factors.

Attempted solution - Right off the back to me this matrix looks ugly so I am thinking of putting it into a better form so essentially applying permutations to the matrix. In part of my professors solution he says: One way to approach this problem performs an priori symmetric permutation i.e., re ordering the rows and columns with the same permutation. Consider $P^T S P$ where $$P = \begin{pmatrix} e_1 & e_2 & e_3 & e_6 & e_7 & e_8 & e_4 & e_5\end{pmatrix}$$
I am wondering about the logic of how we gets $P$. Note that $e_i$ just denotes the position of the $1$. For example $e_1$ is just an $8$ by $1$ matrix with $1$ in the first entry followed by $0$'s in the remaining entries.

So that is question $1$ for me.

Now applying this we get $$\tilde{S} = P^T S P = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \mu_1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \mu_2\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \mu_3\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \delta_1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \delta_2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \delta_3 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \alpha & \beta\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \gamma & \delta\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
Alright, so now we have a better form to the matrix. Now I want to apply the Gauss transform to this matrix in order to get $U$ in the $LU$ factorization. Now since all the nonzero entries that we need to stress over is in the 2 last columns I believe we just need to find $M_6$ and $M_7$ to get my $U$ i.e., I am applying $$M_{n-1}\ldots M_1 A^{(n-1)} = U$$ I hope that is clear if not please let me know. Now once I do this correctly I can simply apply a forward and backward solve to compute the system $Sx = b$.

Any suggestions or comments in regards to this question are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somebody has been studying the Spike algorithm for solving tridiagonal linear systems using two processors :)

Regardless, while permuting the matrix is a valuable theoretical tool, the operation is unnecessary in practice and requires additional time in the form of data movement.

Instead focus on the central 2 by 2 block which engages the 2 unknowns $x_4$ and $x_5$ and nothing else. You permutation reveals why this system is non singular, right? Once this system has been solved using a simple LU factorization, it is straight forward to recover $x_1, x_2$, and $x_3$ and $x_6, x_7$, and $x_8$. If $f$ denotes the right hand side of the (Spike) system $Sx = f$, then you have

$$x_j + \mu_j x_5 = f_j, \quad j=1,2,3,$$

and

$$\delta_j x_4 + x_{5 + j} = f_{5+j}, \quad j = 1,2,3.$$

Comment: Which 2 by 2 block are you referring to? Yes my permutation does reveal that it's nonsingular. I am little confused by this your answer. It turns out that we actually haven't been studying the spike algorithm. What I was planning to do is use the permutation then that would cut down some computations since we can just hit this permitted matrix by the gauss transform matrix $M_6$ and $M_7$ then we will have the upper trapezoidal matrix $U$. Then again your the expert so if your method is easier I will try to keep re reading it

Comment: I am refering to the submatrix which contains the numbers $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$. Ignore the reference to the Spike algorithm. Your professor is a friend of Ahmed Sameh who introduced the Spike algorithm. Your professor simply seized upon the opportunity to make a nice problem and he did not change the notation which made me smile. There is no harm in your approach and it is mathematically equivalent to mine. I was thinking of how it would be implemented and that is irrelevant at this point. Always concentrate on getting a reliable algorithm before you worry about speed.

Comment: I see, by the way one think that I was confused about in the question I posed was how he got the permutation matrix in the form that he defined?

Comment: There is no trick. Placing, say,  $e_6$ in the fourth column of $P$ simply has the effect that the fourth column of AP is equal to $a_6$, the sixth column of $A$. I recommend that you experiment a bit with different permutation matrices.